# How to trigger alarm in a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I want to start alarm when `onReceive()` method of broadcastreceiver is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.clear();
cal.set(2012,2,8,18,16);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

// cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

You can use `context` in `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` instead of `this` in the above code.